In-app purchases are not working when a user tries to purchase a plan from two different devices using the same ID in Flutter
When a user tries to purchase the same subscription or non-consumable item on a second device with the same sandbox account, the system recognizes that the item has already been purchased.
When the user taps on the ok button too many purchases are purchased and the app crashes.
Infinite Loop or Stream Issue.

Yes when you make a purchase with an apple account that purchase belongs to that account. When you use that same account on another device it will see that purchase. This is how it is suppose behave.
This way the purchaser always has access to their purchases. This is the way it needs to behave.
All apple is doing when you make a purchase is logging the purchase, providing you with a payment interface and giving you a purchase event to handle.
You have to handle what that consumable, one-time purchase or subscription does yourself. You should have your own server and database to store your user data and link the purchases to that user.
Firebase and Supabase are great options for rapid server and database development.
Hope that helps
